# bytearray from hex: non-hexadecimal number found

Tags: python-2.7, int, hex, arrays

I need to get a bytearray from an int. I tried this:

```
bytearray.fromhex(hex(8448))
```

I get his error from the interpreter:

```
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 0
```

What's the correct way to get a bytearray from an int?

Comment: `bytearray(hex(8448))` is a bytearray generated from an `int`. But is it the `bytearray` you are looking for?

Comment: @unutbu I can't tell, like I said I would expect this to return a bytearray generated from an int, but it throws a ValueError and stops the program

Comment: To the person who voted to close, if the question is invalid please let me know in the comments so I can modify it or close it if the answer is obvious. I really can't figure out why it's throwing an error.

Comment: do you want `bytearray.fromhex("%x" % 8448)`? `hex(8448)` starts with `'0x'` that is not correct hex string.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you, that was what I was looking for. If you want a few points I can give you the answer.

Comment: your original question is not clear: *"bytearray from an int"* -- what representation? e.g., `marshal.dumps(8448)` or `8448 .to_bytes((8448 .bit_length()  + 7)//8, 'big')` (Python 3). You could post the answer yourself with appropriate examples (input/output).